# use a variable instead of variable name with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df :

```
v1 <- c(100, 20, 5, 30)
v2 <- c(10, 13, 2, 30)
v3 <- c(10, 200, 5, 300)
df <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)


  v1 v2  v3
  1 100 10  10
  2  20 13 200
  3   5  2   5
  4  30 30 300
```

I don't want to use a column name directly with dplyr but refer to a column name stored in a variable (o that I can change it easily throughout a program. This variable is called `column_used`.
in my example, `column_used` is `v1`.

```
column_used <- "v1"
```

I want to use this variable mut it is not working :

```
df %>%
mutate(taux = (column_used/ 100))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`column_used` is only a string and you need to convert it to symbol (i.e. to say that it's not a string, but it's a variable/column name).

You can achieve this e.g. by using [`get()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html) from `base` or [`as.name()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/name.html) or [`sym()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/sym.html) with [`!!`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/nse-force.html) operator from `rlang`:

```
# get()
df %>%
    mutate(taux = get(column_used) / 100)

# !!as.name()
df %>%
    mutate(taux = !!as.name(column_used) / 100)

# !!sym()
df %>%
    mutate(taux = !!sym(column_used) / 100)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr`, here are two options :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(taux = !!sym(column_used)/ 100)
```

Or

```
df %>% mutate(taux = .data[[column_used]]/100)

#   v1 v2  v3 taux
#1 100 10  10 1.00
#2  20 13 200 0.20
#3   5  2   5 0.05
#4  30 30 300 0.30
```

---

In base R, you can do :

```
df$taux <- df[[column_used]]/100
```